# How to Build The icsharpcode for .net compact framework

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, zip

i googled lot, i am not getting the way to build the icsharp source code for .net compact framework..

here is the [link](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx) i,e `http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx` were i am able to download source code, but i am able to build for .net framework not for compact framework 3.5.. i checked the configuration and all i couldn't find..

in the same download page, they have provided the link to download the build binaries, the .net 3.5 CF binary works well..

please let me know the way to build it for .net cf 3.5...

Thanks in advance
Solitaire.

Comment: not an answer, but maybe an alternative. DotNetZip ships a pre-built assembly, usable on .NET CF 2.0 or 3.5.  You don't have to build it.

Comment: yup.. u r right..
i downloaded and used the pre-built binaries..
its working well..but for the sake of knowledge purpose i need to see how to build

Answer (score 1):

```
NAnt.exe -t:netcf-2.0
```

Comment: Hey ..  copyed the Nant.exe to the "SharpZlib.build" folder and if i execute the command it says "invalid framework .netcf-2.0" specified.. wat i need to change.. i am new to this nanat tool :-(

Comment: Do you have .NET CF installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes.. i have.. i have both 2.0CF and 3.5CF.. Next wat to do?

Comment: Hey, i dont have .net 1.1, i have verified the build file it says, if .net 2.0 CF is called go for .net 1.1.. so will it be a problem with the build file. ?